# Feedback on generator functions and class composition in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, generator, elasticsearch

I have written a Python script whose purpose is to read logs from CloudWatch and then post them to ElasticSearch. It is not quite finished but I've progressed far enough that I could benefit from feedback from Python experts, specifically:

- Is the use of Python Generators correct and idiomatic
- Is the use of Class Composition correct and idiomatic
- Anything else style-wise inappropriate for Python 3.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import json
import time
import uuid
import os
import sys

import boto3
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, helpers

client = boto3.client("logs")


def usage() -> None:
    print("Usage: GROUP_NAME=cloudwatch_group ES_HOST=es_host {}".format(
        os.path.basename(__file__)))
    sys.exit(1)

if "GROUP_NAME" not in os.environ:
    usage()
if "ES_HOST" not in os.environ:
    usage()


class CWLogs:
    group_name = os.environ["GROUP_NAME"]

    def events(self) -> None:
        for event in self.__generate_events():
            yield event

    def __generate_streams(self) -> None:
        kwargs = {
            "logGroupName": self.group_name,
        }

        while True:
            stream_batch = client.describe_log_streams(**kwargs)
            yield from stream_batch["logStreams"]
            try:
                kwargs["nextToken"] = stream_batch["nextToken"]
            except KeyError:
                break

    def __generate_events(self) -> None:
        stream_names = \
      [stream["logStreamName"] for stream in self.__generate_streams()]

        for stream_name in stream_names:
            kwargs = {
                "logGroupName":  self.group_name,
                "logStreamName": stream_name,
            }

            while True:
                logs_batch = client.get_log_events(**kwargs)
                yield from logs_batch["events"]
                try:
                    kwargs["nextToken"] = logs_batch["nextToken"]
                except KeyError:
                    break


class ESWriter:
    es_host = os.environ["ES_HOST"]
    elastic = Elasticsearch()

    def post(self, events: object) -> None:
        try:
            response = helpers.bulk(
                self.elastic, self.__transformer(events))
            print("\nRESPONSE:", response)
        except Exception as e:
            print("\nERROR:", e)

    @staticmethod
    def __index_name(timestamp: str) -> str:
        return "eventbridge-auth0-{}".format(
            time.strftime("%Y.%m", time.localtime(timestamp)))

    @staticmethod
    def __normalize(message: str) -> str:
        return message # TODO.

    def __transformer(self, events: object) -> None:
        for event in events:
            yield self.__transform(event)

    def __transform(self, event: dict) -> None:
        timestamp = event["timestamp"]
        index_name = self.__index_name(timestamp)
        message = self.__normalize(event["message"])

        return "\n".join([
            json.dumps({
                "index": {
                    "_id": str(uuid.uuid4()), # TODO. Check
                    "_index": index_name,
                    "_type":  "_doc"}}),
            json.dumps({
                "source": {
                    "@source": "auto-populate script",
                    "@timestamp": timestamp,
                    "@message": message}})])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ESWriter().post(CWLogs().events())
```

Comment: Please note: code should not be changed (updated/added to) once posted, and the code should work as intended.

Comment: Small review: Change your two `if` statements to `for n in ['GROUP_NAME, 'ES_HOST'']: if n not in os.environ: usage()`

Comment: @user229550 Please post answers in answer boxes. If you have even one suggestion and you explain why you think your solution is better; it's a fine answer.

Comment: Okay. ---------

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Code Organization

Your code organization seems non-existent.  You have:

- imports
- code
- function definition
- code
- class definitions
- main-guarded code

Code should be organized in a more consistent structure, like:

- imports
- class definitions
- function definitions
- main-guarded code

The point of using a main-guard is to prevent code from running if the file is imported into another file.  Here, you have two separate code blocks which are unconditionally executed.  This limits code reuse.  For example, imagine someone could use `CWLogs` for their own task, but doesn't need `ESWriter`.  They try `from your_file import CWLogs`, and find their program exits after displaying a cryptic error message about a how to execute a program they are not actually running, due to a missing environment variable they don't actually use.

## sys.exit()

Don't call this.  It terminates the Python interpreter.

Any debugging you may have hoped to do when the program finishes will be impossible, because the entire Python environment imploded.  It is impossible to safely import your file using `try:` `import your_file` `except ImportError:` because Python execution terminates during the import, meaning the program trying to import it unconditionally terminated.  If you try to use `unittest` to test your program, or Sphinx to generate documentation for your program, or any number of other common things, you can't, because your file has unconditionally terminated the Python interpreter.

Don't call it.

Instead:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if {'GROUP_NAME', 'ES_HOST'} <= os.environ.keys():
        main()
    else:
        usage()
```

No need for `usage()` to call `sys.exit()`.  After `usage()` is called, and returns normally, execution reaches the end of the file, which if this is the main program file, will naturally end the program.  Of course, if this is not the main program file, the main guard would have not run either method, the execution would reach the end of the file completing the importation of the file as a module in another program.

## Stop Writing Classes

See "[Stop Writing Classes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)" for a PyCon talk by Jack Diederich.

A class with no instance data members probably shouldn't be a class.  Neither `ESWriter` nor `CWLogs` have any instance data members.

A class with no constructor and only one public method to call shouldn't be a class.  Neither `ESWriter` nor `CWLogs` have a constructor.  Both have a single public method, called immediately after constructing a class instance, so the instance is not even saved.

These should not be classes.

## Private name mangling

[Private name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) is used to prevent private member name collisions when a class is derived from another class, typically when the base class and the derive class are under control of different entities.  For instance, if you derive your own class from a `tkinter.Frame`, and you create a `_validate` method in your class, you could cause the base class to stop functioning properly if it had its own `_validate` method that was just abruptly changed on it.  So, the base class would use `__validate`, the leading double underscore would trigger name "mangling", and replace the name with `_Frame__validate`, so collisions are less likely.

There appears to be no reason for your usage of a double underscore prefix in your method names; a single underscore would be more idiomatic.

## Type Hints

Your type hints are wrong.

For instance, the following is clearly returning a `str`, not `None`:

```
    def __transform(self, event: dict) -> None:
        ...
        return "\n".join( ... )
```

Since `__transformer` is yielding the results of `__transform`, it is not returning `None` either, but should be declared as:

```
from typing import Generator

...

    def __transformer(self, events: object) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
        ...
```

Or simply:

```
from typing import Iterator

...

    def __transformer(self, events: object) -> Iterator[str]:
        ...
```

And `events: object` is virtually meaningless, since everything in Python is an object.  Either use a proper type for it, or don't bother with a type hint at all.

## Generator Expressions

As [yedpodtrziko](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/249020/100620) noted,

```
def __generate_events(self) -> None:
    stream_names = [stream["logStreamName"] for stream in self.__generate_streams()]

    for stream_name in stream_names:
        ...
```

builds up a temporary list, only to immediately iterate through it.  They made a fairly large change in the code to avoid the temporary list.  There is a much smaller change that can be made:

```
def __generate_events(self) -> None:
    stream_names = (stream["logStreamName"] for stream in self.__generate_streams())

    for stream_name in stream_names:
        ...
```

Because it may be hard to see the change, I'll amplify it: the `[...]` got changed to `(...)`.  This means instead of `stream_names` being realized as an in-memory list, it becomes a generator expression, which will produce the values one at a time when asked.

It doesn't make much of a difference here, but if `stream_names` was being passed to a function, instead of being used locally, the change proposed by yedpodtrziko would require reworking code much further away to accept the `stream_obj` and extracting the stream names inside that function.

Comment: Wow thank you, a lot to digest, appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Don't hardcode environment variables inside the classes. Instead of this:

```
class CWLogs:
    group_name = os.environ["GROUP_NAME"]
```

do it like this:

```
class CWLogs:
    group_name = None

    def __init__(self, group_name):
         self.group_name = group_name

if not GROUP_NAME := getenv('GROUP_NAME'):
    usage()
# pass the variable when initializing the class :
CWLogs(GROUP_NAME)
```

This will make the code more maintainable as it does not tightly bound it to the env. variable, but rather to whatever you'll pass there and it will be easier to write tests for such code. Moreover you dont have to repeat the variable in two places, which will increase chance you'll make a typo in one place or forget to modify it in both places when the functionality will change. Same with the `ESWriter` class.

then there's this function:

```
def __generate_events(self) -> None:
    stream_names = [stream["logStreamName"] for stream in self.__generate_streams()]

    for stream_name in stream_names:
        ...
```

Here you have an unnecessary extra loop and extra list allocated in the memory. First you iterate through data returned from `__generate_streams()`, and then you iterate through the same data once again. You can do this instead:

```
def __generate_events(self) -> None:
    for stream_obj in self.__generate_streams():
        stream_name = stream_obj['logStreamName']
```

Comment: Oh yes thank you! Good pickup.